# Getting image size in VBA?

Tags: image, vba, excel, ms-word

In a word document that I've been building some VBA code for, I need to be able to display images on a userform, and also resize the userform to fit whatever image it's presenting.

I was very confused when I tried something like this in the Immediate Box (the image file is actually only 675 pixels in width):

```
? LoadPicture("C:\Users\arose\Desktop\Security Control Doc\Images\AC1.bmp").Width
  17859
```

Eventually I discovered that this is due to VBA using some unit other than pixels. Twips, or something like that. But I really need to have image sizes in pixels, so I mucked around, found roughly what the conversion factor is, and I'm using this:

```
Function TwipsToPixels(Twips As Long) As Long

    TwipsToPixels = Twips / 25.477

End Function
```

This has helped, but it is not particularly accurate. So my question is, does anyone have a more elegant and precise way of getting image sizes in VBA?

Comment: *How to Convert Twips to Pixels* http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;94927

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default unit of measurement in VBA is **twips**: screen-independent unit of measurement that is equal to 1/20 of a point, or 1/1,440 of an inch. There are 567 twips in a centimeter.

Pixels are screen dependent units, so the two functions/properties `TwipsPerPixelX` and `TwipsPerPixelY` should do the trick.